# Intersection of two equally long lines in a set with diameter $1$

Tags: geometry

Let $A := \{x,y,z,w\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a set with diameter less or equal to $1$. Let $L(x,y)$ and $L(z,w)$ be the linesegments between the points $x,y$ resp. $z,w$. If both lines have length $1$ then they must intersect.

How to prove this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z$ and $w$ must lie inside or on the boundary of this figure:

[image]

If $z$ or $w$ lie on the line $L(x.y)$, then the lines intersect; so assume that they don't. If $z$ is in the top half, then every other point in the top half (and not on $L(x,y)$) is at a distance of less that $1$ from $z$. So if $L(z,w) = 1$, $w$ must lie in the bottom half.

Comment: Thanks. I just had the same idea now.